# I want to play Minecraft with my friend in my world but it always says unable to join world on their screen

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am using an iPad and they are using an iPhone.I tried a lot of things.

Comment: you are both on the same network, right?

Comment: @Topcode they dont have to be, xbox live doesnt require LAN

Answer (score 1):

This is going to require a bit more information.

1st - Make sure that both of you are signed in with a microsoft account on your devices. AND you are friends with each other.

2nd - Make sure to click the ‘edit’ (the pen icon) button before you open your world, select multiplayer and make sure all options are on.

3rd - Have your friend go to the ‘friends’ tab on their phone after a bit your world should appear, clicking/tapping this